# Minimum Product Weight in a Graph with 2 weight functions

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

Hello Community,
Given an undirected graph G = (V,E) where E has 2 weight functions w1(e) --> {1,2,..9} and w2(e) --> {1,2...9} with given a source vertex s and destination vertex t. we can measure
the weight of this path with respect to w1 and with respect to w2 separately.The two weights
are denoted, respectively, by w1(p) and w2(p). The product weight of a path p is defined as w(prod) p = w1(p) * w2(p). We wish to find the minimum product-weight paths from s to t in G.


 First, I tried Dijkstra on the graph to find the shortest paths with respect to w1 and w2. But after several test cases where the weights might be the same, it fails.

 Second, I tried MST algorithm(Kruskal's). It does not get a unique path when the weights are the same which does not lead to the best solution.

 Third, BFS and DFS will traverse through the graph, but I am clueless on how it will give the minimum product weight path.


 Any help related to this problem is much appreciated.